# ObjC delegate callback in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In ObjC, I've got a function declared as

```
-(void)fubar:(void(^)(NSDictionary *))callback;
```

This is how I will use in ObjC

```
fubar(^(NSDictionary *dict) {
   console.log(dict);
})
```

How do I use the same in Swift after bridging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's the last parameter it can be used as a trailing closure:

```
fubar { (dict) in
  print(dict) // prints dictionary 
}
```

Or even shorter

```
fubar() { 
  print($0) // prints dictionary
}
```

[Read the section on Trailing Closures in Apple's Swift book for more info.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102)

Comment: Thanks buddy! I got so so confused by the xcode hints and all the [NSObject : AnyObject] syntax